# How to troubleshoot Google Chrome Sync issues?

Tags: google-chrome, synchronization

I am using custom sync options to synchronize only some of the artifacts from a Google chrome installation - just Bookmarks, Extensions and Open Tabs. All three are working on well on my two windows computers - but on the Linux machine, I am not getting the extensions. I have tried wiping the Linux Chrome data (by removing ~/.config/google-chrome/ and re-configuring it, the the problem remains the same.

I am wondering if there are any logs that the chrome browser produces that can give me a hint on what the problem might be.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is not a bug but a "feature", different support of extension per OS, but seems there might be hope this is fixed in future releases see:

- [Chrome Web Store to get multi-platform app support for Windows, Mac, Linux, Android, iOS, and Chrome OS](http://thenextweb.com/google/2013/03/26/chrome-web-store-to-get-multi-platform-app-support-for-windows-mac-linux-android-ios-and-chrome-os/)
- [Other Deployment Options](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions.html)